# Bootstrap 2-Col Format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, breakpoints

I want to create a **2-col 6/6 section**. The form is responsive but when i try to add **contact-links** section outside of **contact-form** it doesn't work. What is the correct way to format it in bootstrap?

- **contact-form** section (floated to left)
- **contact-links** section (floated to right)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRgOGN

```
<div class="contact-links">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <ul>
           <li>Facebook</li>
           <li>Twiiter</li>
           <li>Call Us</li>
           <li>Find Us</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="contact-form">
```

To this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="contact-form">
```

And replace `col-md-6` with `col-md-12` in the input groups within the form.
 Also replace:

```
<div class="contact-links">
   <div class="col-md-6">
   ......
   </div>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div class="contact-links  col-md-6">
   ......
</div>
```

This should work.